# Nullable foreign key on room

Tags: android, database, foreign-keys, android-room

I would know if that is possible to create a possible null reference on foreign key with room.

For now my database structure is like this :

```java
@Entity(tableName = "A")
class A {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
}

@Entity(tableName = "B")
class B{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
}

@Entity(tableName = "C", foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = A.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "foreign_id_a"), @ForeignKey(entity = B.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "foreign_id_b")})
class C{
    public long id;
    public long foreign_id_a;
    public long foreign_id_b;   
}
```

I would like to be able to insert the following objects :

```
C(id=1, foreign_id_a=1, foreign_id_b=1)
C(id=1, foreign_id_a=null, foreign_id_b=1)
C(id=1, foreign_id_a=1, foreign_id_b=null)
```

But the previous insert with null value give this error : 
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (Sqlite code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)

Is there a way to make it possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just change foreign key types from `long` to `Long`.

In Java, `long` type cannot be `null` and therefore Room generates this column as `NOT NULL`. Also, the `C` class does not have `@PrimaryKey` specified.

```
@Entity(tableName = "C", foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = A.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "foreign_id_a"), @ForeignKey(entity = B.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "foreign_id_b")})
class C{
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public Long foreign_id_a;
    public Long foreign_id_b;   
}
```

In Kotlin, `Long` type is non-null. If you want to insert nullable foreign keys, you need to change the fields to nullable type `Long?`.

```
@Entity(tableName = "C", foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = A::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["foreign_id_a"]), ForeignKey(entity = B::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["foreign_id_b"])])
class C{
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long = 0
    var foreign_id_a: Long? = null
    var foreign_id_b: Long? = null
}
```

Comment: What if we use Kotlin?

Comment: @TheFedex87 you can just use nullable type `Long?`, please see the edit.

Comment: I had already tried, but even if I use Long? and try to use a null key I get an error of constraint failed

Comment: Then you might have a different problem. Are you inserting object with multiple foreign keys? If you are inserting non null foreign keys, do corresponding rows with primary keys exist in the table you are referencing?