# Room - How to set nullable Foreign Key

Tags: kotlin, foreign-keys, android-room, room

In my Kotlin Android codebase I have the following 2 entities..

```
@Entity(
tableName = ModuleConfiguration.tableName,
primaryKeys = [ModuleConfiguration.COL_ID],
foreignKeys = arrayOf(
    ForeignKey(
        entity = Module::class,
        parentColumns = [Module.COL_ID],
        childColumns = [ModuleConfiguration.COL_MODULE_ID],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    ),
    ForeignKey(
        entity = Group::class,
        parentColumns = [Group.COL_ID],
        childColumns = [ModuleConfiguration.COL_GROUP_ID]
    )
)
)
class ModuleConfiguration(
@ColumnInfo(name = COL_ID)
var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_TABLE)
var table: String,

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_FIELD_NAME)
var fieldName: String,

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_FIELD_LABEL)
var fieldLabel: String,

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_FIELD_TYPE)
var fieldType: ModuleConfigurationItemType,

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_GROUP_ID)
var groupId: String?,

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_MODULE_ID)
var moduleId: String,

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_POSITION)
var position: Int,

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_VISIBLE)
var visible: Int = 1, //Usually visible

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_READ_ONLY)
var readOnly: Int = 0, //Usually false

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_REQUIRED)
var required: Int = 0, //Usually false

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_CREATED_AT)
var createdAt: Long = CustomDateTimeUtil.getTodayInUTC(),

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_UPDATED_AT)
var updatedAt: Long = CustomDateTimeUtil.getTodayInUTC()
) : Cloneable, Serializable, Parcelable  {

constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    fieldType = ModuleConfigurationItemType.valueOf(parcel.readString() ?: FieldType.UNKNOWN.name),
    groupId = parcel.readString(),
    moduleId = parcel.readString() ?: "",
    position = parcel.readInt(),
    visible = parcel.readInt(),
    readOnly = parcel.readInt(),
    required = parcel.readInt(),
    createdAt = parcel.readLong(),
    updatedAt = parcel.readLong()
) {
}

fun getViewType() : ModuleConfigurationItemType {
    return this.fieldType
}

override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    return super.equals(other)
}

override fun hashCode(): Int {
    return super.hashCode()
}

override fun clone(): Any {
    return super.clone()
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(id)
    parcel.writeString(table)
    parcel.writeString(fieldName)
    parcel.writeString(fieldLabel)
    parcel.writeString(fieldType.name)
    parcel.writeString(groupId)
    parcel.writeString(moduleId)
    parcel.writeInt(position)
    parcel.writeInt(visible)
    parcel.writeInt(readOnly)
    parcel.writeInt(required)
    parcel.writeLong(createdAt)
    parcel.writeLong(updatedAt)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<ModuleConfiguration> {

    const val tableName = "module_configuration"

    const val COL_ID = "id"
    const val COL_MODULE_ID = "module_id"
    const val COL_TABLE = "table"
    const val COL_FIELD_NAME = "field_name"
    const val COL_FIELD_LABEL = "field_label"
    const val COL_FIELD_TYPE = "field_type"
    const val COL_GROUP_ID = "group_id"
    const val COL_VISIBLE = "visible"
    const val COL_READ_ONLY = "read_only"
    const val COL_REQUIRED = "required"
    const val COL_POSITION = "position"
    const val COL_CREATED_AT = "created_at"
    const val COL_UPDATED_AT = "updated_at"
    const val COL_CLIENT_ID = "client_id"

    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ModuleConfiguration {
        return ModuleConfiguration(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ModuleConfiguration?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
}
```

and Group Entity

```
@Entity(
tableName = Group.tableName,
primaryKeys = [Group.COL_ID]
)
class Group(
@ColumnInfo(name = COL_ID)
var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_NAME)
var name: String,

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_CREATED_AT)
var createdAt: Long = CustomDateTimeUtil.getTodayInUTC(),

@ColumnInfo(name = COL_UPDATED_AT)
var updatedAt: Long = CustomDateTimeUtil.getTodayInUTC()
) : Cloneable, Parcelable  {

constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readLong(),
    parcel.readLong()
) {
}

override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    return super.equals(other)
}

override fun hashCode(): Int {
    return super.hashCode()
}

override fun clone(): Any {
    return super.clone()
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(id)
    parcel.writeString(name)
    parcel.writeLong(createdAt)
    parcel.writeLong(updatedAt)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Group> {

    const val tableName = "group"

    const val COL_ID = "id"
    const val COL_NAME = "name"
    const val COL_CREATED_AT = "created_at"
    const val COL_UPDATED_AT = "updated_at"
    const val COL_CLIENT_ID = "client_id"

    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Group {
        return Group(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Group?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
}
```

My problem is that I am trying to set nullable foreign key, as you can see in entity named ModuleConfiguration, there is column named group_id, which is nullable.

```
@ColumnInfo(name = COL_GROUP_ID)
var groupId: String?,
```

Since, this column belongs to other entity named Group, I am trying to make it foreign key, but when I do that, I am getting following error

SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)

On searching online, I found following answers on stackoverflow:

[Android with Room - How to set a foreign key nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933887/android-with-room-how-to-set-a-foreign-key-nullable)
or
[Nullable foreign key on room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492719/nullable-foreign-key-on-room)

but this did not help me as these answer suggest to change primitive types like int or long into non-primitive types like Integer or Long for allowing them to be null. I am already using String as type.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question, because as it is really hard to understand, that's why you're getting downvotes. @whomever downvoted: it would have been great if you left a comment.

Comment: ok doing it now :(

Comment: is it any better now ?

Comment: Can it be that you have constraint's problem with another foreign key `moduleId` that isn't nullable?

Comment: maybe you are right, once I removed both foreign key constraints it worked.. removing the once I thought was causing issue also did not solve it.. after some hit and trial.. i think it might be issue of sequence .. how I am adding values... as there are quite a few rows that I am initiating database with.. going through them now